# PL/SQL IF loop not working in my package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write my procedure as follows:

```
begin
if(condn1) then

statements;

end if ;

exception part

end ;

begin
if(condn2) then

statements;

end if ;

exception part

end ;
```

When I try to compile this package I get the following error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
509/5    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
         null pragma raise return select update while with
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
         insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
         merge pipe purge
         The symbol "case" was substituted for "WHEN" to continue.

545/10   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
         following:
         case
```

Comment: which db u r using.. also you are using case and when need to see the code to say what is going wrong

Comment: Could you please provide the exact code?

Comment: Your obfuscated code does not contain the keyword `when`, so it's impossible for the code in your question to generate the error you ahve posted. Please post the real code.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include several exception parts, you must include a whole block for each exception part you want. The block structure is:

```
DECLARE  [Optional]
  ...    [Optional]
BEGIN
  ...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN ... THEN
    ...
END;
```

Thus, your code with 2 exception parts should be something similar to the following code:

```
DECLARE
   your_variables;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    IF condition_1 THEN
      statements;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN your_exceptions_for_part_1 THEN
      ...
  END;


  BEGIN
    IF condition_2 THEN
      statements;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN your_exceptions_for_part_2 THEN
      ...
  END;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN common_exceptions THEN
    ...
END;
```